# Is there a name for the isosceles triangle whose height is equal to its base?

Tags: geometry, terminology

This triangle seems "special" to me, because its height is equal to the length of its base, so when inscribed in a square the top vertex is exactly the middle of the top side of the square.

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

> Is there a name for the isosceles triangle whose height is equal to its base?

Seems useful in architecture, engineering and maybe have some symbolism attached to it. Does it have a name?